# Angular 1.5 Components + ng-model $formatters and $parsers

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-components

I would like to know how to use $formatters and $parsers with angular 1.5 components. Can someone post an example.

Or is there something similar that I can use.

Comment: Use the [ng-form directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) to bind the API to scope. (Don't bind `ng-model` with component isolate scope.) Then read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implementing Custom Form Controls Using `ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)

Comment: I'd love to see this question get a nice answer.
@georgeawg why not "bind ng-model with component isolate scope" ?

Comment: The reason this has gone unanswered for so long might be because the one way binding/return model of components kinda makes this moot.  If you're avoiding two way binding (which is always a good idea), you have the power to transform your model => view in `$onInit` and view => model when the user is done messing with the value (by calling an update (`'&'`) function and passing the new value using `ng-change` or some other user triggered action for example).

Comment: I'd love to see an answer to this too.

Comment: I'll post an example soon. We use two-way binding in our application all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of a component called `example`. This takes in a object that contains `firstName` and `secondName`. It then displays a combination of the `firstName` and `secondName`. If the object changes from the outside the formatter will fire followed by the render. If you want to trigger a change from the inside, you need to call `this.ngModel.$setViewValue(newObject)` and this would trigger the parser.

```
    class example {
        /*@ngInject*/
        constructor() {}

        // In the post link we need to add our formatter, parser and render to the ngmodel.
        $postLink() {
            this.ngModel.$formatters.push(this.$formatter.bind(this));
            this.ngModel.$parsers.push(this.$parser.bind(this));
            this.ngModel.$render = this.$render.bind(this);
        }

        // The formatter is used to intercept the model value coming in to the controller
        $formatter(modelValue) {
            const user = {
                name: `${modelValue.firstName} ${modelValue.secondName}`
            };

            return user;
        }

        // The parser is used to intercept the view value before it is returned to the original source
        // In this case we want to turn it back to it's original structure what ever that may be.
        $parser(viewValue) {
            // We know from out formatter that our view value will be an object with a name field

            const namesParts = viewValue.name.split(' ');

            const normalisedUser = {
                firstName: namesParts[0],
                secondName: namesParts[1],
            };

            return normalisedUser;
        }

        // This will fire when ever the model changes. This fires after the formatter.
        $render() {
            this.displayName = this.ngModel.$viewValue.name;
        }
    }

class ExampleComponent
{
    bindings = {};
    controller = Example;
    require = {
        ngModel: 'ngModel',
    };
}

component('example', new ExampleComponent());


    // Template for example component
    <span>
        {{ $ctrl.displayName }}
    </span>

    // Using the above component somewhere    
    <example ng-model="userModel"></example>
```